# Accessing client certificate from Iphone's Key chain with Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I built an apps with Monotouch (c#) that required client certificate authentication to connect https server. The client certificate will be distributed per mail, and the apps user should save the client certificate on the Iphone.

Since the certificate will be stored in the Iphone, how can I access the certificate stored in the Iphone with Monotouch? Is there any API for this?

Could someone provide me any link, sample codes, or docs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access system installed certificates on the iPhone.

The keyring APIs are merely useful to manage your own certificates that you install in your application.